# How do I get a random item from a ListBox, then compare it in C#?

Tags: c#, random, listbox, compare

Currently, I have this:

```
Random random = new 
random.Next(1, strings.Items.Count);
strings.Select();
strings.SelectedItem = strings.Items[Convert.ToInt32(random)];
var str = strings.SelectedItem;
if (str == "stuff")
{
  //Here
}
```

It doens't give any errors in the output, but it won't run when I test it. I get an `InvalidCastException`, saying it was unable to cast an object of type `System.Random` to the type `System.IConvertible`.

[image]

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code shouldn't compile (You missed `new Random();` on the first line). It should be:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber  = random.Next(1, strings.Items.Count);
strings.Select();
strings.SelectedItem = strings.Items[randomNumber];
var str = strings.SelectedItem;
if (str == "stuff")
{
    //Here
}
```

You are getting the exception on following line, which tries to convert `random` object to the int, that you can't do and that is why you are getting the exception.

```
strings.Items[Convert.ToInt32(random)]
```

It is wrong to index the `string.Items` based on the `random` object. It should be the random number returned by the `random` object, not the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to following:

```
Random random = new 
int rnd = random.Next(1, strings.Items.Count);
strings.Select();
strings.SelectedItem = strings.Items[rnd];
var str = strings.SelectedItem;
if (str == "stuff")
{
  //Here
}
```

Comment: So, what was the original problem? Why does this code fix that problem? Good answers require an *explanation*, that's how we learn something instead of just copying-and-pasting magic code.